# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: json, angular, typescript

[here is code  i am trying to access object of objects.
template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZEQl.png)

```
<table class="table table-striped"> 
  <tr *ngFor="let response of response"> 
    <td><b>ID</b><br>{{ response.user_id }} </td> 
    <td><b>Name:</b> {{ response.first_name }}</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code please

Comment: export class ViewUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  response: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit()  {
    this.getData();     
  }


  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/customers')
       .subscribe(
         (response) => {this.response = response;
         console.log(response);
       })
  }


}

Comment: <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr *ngFor="let response of response">
         <td><b>ID</b><br>{{ response.user_id }} </td>
         <td><b>Name:</b> {{ response.first_name }}</td>      
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: Please don't post codes in the comment section. Update them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response isn't directly an array. It is an object with properties that contain the array. From the image you posted, you could try the following

```html
<table class="table table-striped"> 
  <tr *ngFor="let customer of response._embedded.customers">  <!-- access properties here -->
    <td>
      <b>ID</b><br>
      {{ customer.user_id }} 
    </td> 
    <td>
      <b>Name:</b> {{ customer.first_name }}
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry i have hard time to add code here. i just added typescript file. I was trying something like that didn't get it work yet!

Comment: You could take the Stackoverflow tour here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It introduces some basic functionalities of the website.

Comment: get it solved wasn't exactly but give me good hint. Thank You!